# Crm 2011 Plugin doesn't trigger on Message "RemoveMember"

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I've  built a Custom Plugin for CRM 2011.  Basically, the same plug-in has been deployed in two different environments: Test and Pro. 
These environments are obviously twins. Same entities, same configurations etc..

The plug-in, triggers on update of a specific boolean field. On true value,  triggers and add a contact to a list. So, with the same logic, on the same field set on false, triggers and remove the contact from the list. 
Now, on "test environments", it triggers on both situations. But on "Pro environments" , when  the boolean field it's set on false, it doesn't trigger!

I discard any supposition of a logic bug implementation. For the reason that it works well on the the first environment.
Above, it doesn't write any log  in this case. And it makes me more convinced that it doesn't trigger  at all.

Does anybody knows , what could be the problem?

Comment: Well if it works well in one environment and not in the other. I assume you have made a mistake on the plugin registration process somwhere. Check that your step and image (if applicable) is registerd correctly in your production environment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer.  So, as I said, in the prod environment, Both action, (AddMember / removeMember) are registered with the same step: Message update. That's  the strange thing because on  AddMember it Works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make absolutely sure that your theory is correct. Throw an Exception right at the top of your plugin, and see if you get the Exception pop-up in CRM on both True/False.  If you do, then the plugin *is* firing on both a True/False update and there is something wrong with your code - I can't imagine what it is since it works in dev, but at least you've proven that it isn't the CRM plugin infrastructure's fault.

If you don't get the pop-up Exception for the False scenario, the only other possible answer is that CRM's plugin infrastructure doesn't think that field should be updated. When the screen refreshes after an update to False, does that field still show False or does it go back to True? It is possible to "cancel" a field update by removing it from the field list of the entity that gets passed into your Pre-Operation plugin - is it possible there are other plugins that execute before this one and maybe cancel that field update?

Last thing I can think of: you are saying Update but do you mean Create? If that boolean field's default value is set to False in Prod but not in Dev, when you create the entity, that field won't be included in the field update list (and thus not fire your plugin) if it is set to False because the system already knows the default value to use on a Create is False.

Comment: Hi josh, thanks a lot for answer. So, If I change the default field, he situation get reversed!Then,  I've been doing some tests and I figure out that it doesn't trigger only if I call multiple rows. For example, if I select many contacts to be inserted into a list. If I call a single contact , it works!